# Соединение с mysql + php в openshift

Tags: php, mysql, openshift

Моя бд mysql находится на облаке openshift, я пытаюсь получить данные с бд через php-скрипт с запросом, но он не работает, я попытался найти проблему и заметил, что enviroment variables для php не возвращают нужно значения. Скажите что это может быть?

```
<?php
    define('DB_NAME', getenv('OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME'));
    define('DB_HOST', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST')); // 127.0.250.1
    define('DB_PORT', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT')); // 3306
    define('DB_USER', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME')); // admin
    define('DB_PASS', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD')); //      
    define('DB_SOCKET', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_SOCKET')); //   $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DIR/socket/mysql.sock
    define('DB_STRING', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_URL'));
    echo(DB_NAME);
    echo(DB_USER);
?>
```

Данные из enviroment variable DB_NAME выводит а все остальные не выводит

Comment: Пароль-то с логином показывать не следовало.

Comment: эти данные не мои

Comment: @Contact значит дважды не следовало

Answer (score 1):

Когда хостился на openshift. Тоже была такая проблема.

Решил тем что логин, пароль и хост. прописывал так.

У них PHP просто не все видит.